# How to grep for specific format

Tags: linux, grep

I have a .txt which has following strings.

```
ANEW.0000+0530-0015+0530_NEW
ANEW.0000+0530-0100+0530_NEW
ANEW.0045+0530-0100+0530_NEW
ANEW.0100+0530-0115+0530_NEW
ANEW.0100+0530-0200+0530_NEW
ANEW.0145+0530-0200+0530_NEW
ANEW.0200+0530-0215+0530_NEW
ANEW.0200+0530-0300+0530_NEW
ANEW.0245+0530-0300+0530_NEW
ANEW.0300+0530-0315+0530_NEW
ANEW.0300+0530-0400+0530_NEW
ANEW.0345+0530-0400+0530_NEW
ANEW.0400+0530-0415+0530_NEW
ANEW.0400+0530-0500+0530_NEW
ANEW.0445+0530-0500+0530_NEW
ANEW.0500+0530-0515+0530_NEW
ANEW.0500+0530-0600+0530_NEW
ANEW.0545+0530-0600+0530_NEW
ANEW.0600+0530-0615+0530_NEW
ANEW.0600+0530-0700+0530_NEW
ANEW.0645+0530-0700+0530_NEW
ANEW.0700+0530-0715+0530_NEW
ANEW.0700+0530-0800+0530_NEW
ANEW.0745+0530-0800+0530_NEW
ANEW.0800+0530-0815+0530_NEW
ANEW.0800+0530-0900+0530_NEW
ANEW.0845+0530-0900+0530_NEW
ANEW.0900+0530-0915+0530_NEW
ANEW.0900+0530-1000+0530_NEW
ANEW.0945+0530-1000+0530_NEW
```

I need to grep all the lines which has like 0400+0530-0500+0530,0500+0530-0600+0530 etc . Can some one show me how to use grep command to get the required output?

I have tried as below. But it is not working.

```
cat myfile.txt |grep "*00+0530-*00+0530*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the substrings with four digits are timestamps, it appears you want to exclude the lines that contain timestamps from a quarter past the hour or quarter to the hour.

To do this, use `grep` like so:

```bsh
grep -v -e '[0-9][0-9]15' -e '[0-9][0-9]45' file.txt
```

or shorter,

```bsh
grep -v '[0-9][0-9][14]5' file.txt
```

The two regular expressions here will match any timestamp from quarter past and a quarter to the hour, anywhere on a line.  If either expression matches, the line is *not* extracted from the file due to the `-v` option, which inverts the sense of the match.

The result of this command, given the input in the question, is

```
ANEW.0000+0530-0100+0530_NEW
ANEW.0100+0530-0200+0530_NEW
ANEW.0200+0530-0300+0530_NEW
ANEW.0300+0530-0400+0530_NEW
ANEW.0400+0530-0500+0530_NEW
ANEW.0500+0530-0600+0530_NEW
ANEW.0600+0530-0700+0530_NEW
ANEW.0700+0530-0800+0530_NEW
ANEW.0800+0530-0900+0530_NEW
ANEW.0900+0530-1000+0530_NEW
```

The issue with your expression is that a `*` at the start of a basic regular expression matches a literal `*`, and there are no such characters in your data.  Furthermore, the `0*` at the end matches the character `0` zero or more times, and `-*` in the middle matches zero or more dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
grep '00+0530-..00+0530' myfile.txt
```

Dots (`.`) are inserted in the search string for any character. You do not need `cat`.